# Find the Laurent series of $\frac{z+2}{z-1}$ where i) $0 < |z| < 1$ and ii) $|z-1| > 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, laurent-series

I am struggling to find the algebraic manipulation to find the Laurent series of $\frac{z+2}{z-1}$ where i) $0 < |z| < 1$ and ii) $|z-1| > 1$

I tried putting the numerator as $(z-1) + 3$ but then my problem is that I cannot obtain an expression of the form $\frac{1}{1+w}$ to obtain the Laurent expansion since the expression becomes $ 1+\frac{3}{z-1}$.

Can someone help me find the algebraic manipulation to solve these types of problems please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $z+2/(z-1)$?

Comment: Yes I do, thanks for helping edit, I will include that code in the future

Comment: (+1) For improving your post. You're welcome.

Comment: Are you sure about $|z-1|>1$? I think that it should be $|z|>1$.

Comment: It is strange, but there is no error. It is supposed to be $|z-1| > 1$

Comment: When $|z|<1$ the function is analytic, and the Laurent series is the same as the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

For *i)* you're on the right track. Just recall the formula of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Closed-form_formula) $\sum_{n \ge0} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$ converges when $|x|<1$.

For *ii)* we see that the Laurent series for $|z-1| > 1$ is precisely the Laurent series for $|z-1|>0$, which you have already calculated to be
$$
\frac{z+2}{z-1} = 1 + 3 \frac{1}{z-1} \tag{1}
$$
which converges for all $|z-1|>0$.

---

To explain *ii)* need to recall a bit of Complex Analysis theory. Laurent's theorem states that given a function $f(z)$ we can express it as the series around some point $c$ as follows
$$
f(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n (z-c)^n
$$
where the coefficients $a_n$ are given by
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{(z-c)^{n+1}} \, dz \tag{2}
$$
where $\gamma$ is *any* positively oriented closed Jordan curve lying inside an annulus $A$ where $f(z)$ is holomorphic.
Now, the above is a mouthful, but the key thing to notice is that the curve $\gamma$ over which you integrate is arbitrary as long as it's in the region $A$ over which the function is holomorphic. This is a consequence of the homotopic version of Cauchy's integral theorem which states that given two smooth closed curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ in some region $U$ which are homotopic (which just means you can stretch one into the other smoothly), then for some function $f(z)$ which is holomorphic on $U$
$$
\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) dz = \int_{\gamma_2} f(z) dz \tag{3}
$$
are equal!

Because of the above, we see that if our function $f(z)$ happens to be holomorphic in a bigger region $U\supset U^*$, then if we have some $\gamma^* \in U^*$ over which we integrate $(2)$, then the integral will be the same as the one we would get by deforming $\gamma^* \to \gamma \in U \setminus U^*$.

In our case, we see that the function $f(z) = \frac{z+2}{z-1}$ is holomorphic for all $|z| \neq 1 \iff |z-1|>0$, but notice that this region encapsulates the sub-region we're interested in $|z-1|>1$. This means that if we choose some curve $\gamma \subset \{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z-1|>1\}$ over which to calculate $(2)$, since the function $\frac{f(z)}{(z-1)^{n+1}}$ will be holomorphic for all $|z-1| > 0$ we can deform our $\gamma \to \gamma_1 \subset \{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z-1| > 0\} \setminus \{z \in \mathbb{C}:|z-1|>1\}$ and we'll still get the same values of $a_n$, and hence, the same Laurent series.

---

The above discussion is the reason why these Laurent exercises are usually presented with regions that have extreme points at the singularities of the function $f(z)$, because if you have some other sub-region where the function is holomorphic then the function will continue to be holomorphic until you hit one of these singularities, so you might as well stretch the curve $\gamma$ to cover the whole thing.

Lastly, if you want some expression which *only* converges  on $|z-1| > 1$ you can do
$$
\frac{x+2}{x-1} = \frac{4}{x-1} + \frac{x-2}{x-1} = \frac{4}{x-1} + \left[\frac{1}{1- \left(\frac{1}{x-1} \right)}\right]^{-1} = \frac{4}{x-1}+\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x-1)^{-n} \right]^{-1} \tag{4}
$$
As is, equation $(4)$ will only converge for $|z-1| > 1$. However, the above is not really the Laurent series, since if you try to write it in the form $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n (z-1)^n$ you'll see that you just arrive at the expression in $(1)$ which we already argued has a bigger radius of convergence.

Comment: Ok so then for i) we just obtain $-\sum_{n \ge0} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$ but what about the (z-2)\$ on the top. The only other answer I obtained was 3 $\sum_{n \ge0}$ $\frac{3^n}{(z-1)^n} = \frac{z+2}{z-1}$

Comment: Remember you already simplified $\frac{z+2}{z-1}$. Notice that
$$
\frac{z+2}{z-1} = 1 - 3 \frac{1}{1-z} = 1 - 3 \sum_{n\ge0} z^n = -2 -3z-3z^2 - 3z^3...
$$

Comment: Ya I understand that but from what I understand you indicated that expression is valid for ii), so are you saying that i) has the same expansion? Why would that be

Comment: No. The Laurent expansion for _i)_ is what I wrote in my previous comment. The Laurent expansion for _ii)_ is $1 + 3 \frac{1}{z-1}$. If you're referencing what I wrote at the end of my answer, I mention that you will arrive at equation $(1)$, which is just the number that denotes the equation $\frac{z+2}{z-1} = 1 + 3 \frac{1}{z-1}$, not a mention of question _i)_.